# Moment of inertia hollow sphere with inner and outer radius

Tags: integration, physics

I'm trying to determine the moment of inertia of a hollow sphere, with inner radius 'a' and outer radius 'R'.

A lot of websites give me different solutions, so I don't know which one I have to use. Hopefully someone can help me, and give the calculation of the moment of intertia :)

https://physics.ucsd.edu/neurophysics/courses/physics_2bl/p2bl_experiment_2_notes.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia#Moments_of_inertia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment of inertia of the shell would be given by:
$$\frac{2m}5 * \frac{R^5-a^5}{r^3-a^3}$$

https://physics.ucsd.edu/neurophysics/courses/physics_2bl/p2bl_experiment_2_notes.pdf 
has the whole calculation under 0.0.1. 
The final answer is just a factorized form, if that's what's confusing you, look at the second last step and so on.

Comment: Thanks! I see that if a -> 0, it's exactly the moment of inertia of the solid sphere. But if a -> R, it should be the moment of intertia of the hollow sphere (2/5 * M * R^2), but I don't see how that's possible..

Comment: in the expression (R^5-a^5)/(R^3-a^3), take the limit as a approaches R. You will find that the answer is (5R^2)/3

Answer (score 0):

$$ MI = \frac25 ( M R^2 - m r^2 ),\, \frac{r^3}{R^3} = \frac{m}{M}. $$

where $M,m,R,r$ are for solid spheres.